# Log4j2 write to CSV for Excel without garbled characters

Tags: java, excel, csv, log4j, byte-order-mark

I am using Log4j2 to write a `output.csv` file with UTF-8 charset.

After the output is complete, everything works well. But when I open the `output.csv` by Excel-2016, every Chinese characters become garbled.

I have noticed that Excel opens csv with ANSI encode by default, so many UTF-8 characters cannot display correctly.
One of the solution is adding `byte order mark (BOM)` at beginning of my `output.csv` by myself.

See: [java-how-to-add-and-remove-bom-from-utf-8-file](https://mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-add-and-remove-bom-from-utf-8-file/)

But I hope log4j2 can do that for me. Is there any better solution/workaround ?

Here is my log4j2.xml

```xml
<RollingFile 
  name="Chat-Appender" 
  fileName="${logSavePath}/output.csv"
  filePattern="${logArchivePath}/output_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.csv">
  <CsvParameterLayout 
      delimiter="," 
      format="Excel"
      header="id,question,answer\n"
      charset="UTF-8" />
  <Policies>
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" />
  </Policies>
</RollingFile>
```

Thanks for your help and suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a BOM at the beginning of the file, you just need to insert it at the beginning of the `header` parameter:

```xml
<CsvParameterLayout delimiter="," 
                    format="Excel"
                    header="&#xFEFF;id,question,answer\n"
                    charset="UTF-8" />
```

Comment: It works perfectlly! But could you please tell me what does `&#xFEFF;` mean?  Thnak you.

Comment: It is the [XML entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) for the `U+FEFF` character (BOM).